# how to move the whole row and put it in the order of time

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using this script to move a whole line in a Google sheet.

I would like to be able to move the line and put it in order by time.
In the sheet I have a column with time.

```
function moveDown() {
    var d = getData();
    d.sheet.insertRowsAfter(d.row+d.height, d.height);
    d.selection.copyTo(d.sheet.getRange(d.row+d.height+3, 1, d.height, d.width));
    d.sheet.deleteRows(d.row, d.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Append your data and sort by the correct column?

```
function moveDown() {
     sheet.appendRow(["3-12","Something","Something"]);
     sheet.sort(1);
}
```